# How to create an index having instances?

Tags: faunadb

Having existing data in a class (within a database)... I am not able to create an index (of type "all") and return the data that was inserted before the creation of the new index.

I have tried to do it programmatically (python) and via web interface.

I hope to be able to recover pre-existing data when a new index is created.

Comment: Hey, would you mind jumping onto the [community slack](https://community-invite.fauna.com/) and pinging me there (Ben Edwards)? I think that might be a better place to get to the bottom of this then we can update this question with an answer.

Comment: Alternatively: can you edit to explain what errors you are seeing when creating the index? (and include the query you are running to create the index)

Comment: I'll do See u there!

Answer (score 3):

Fauna automatically builds indices on creation adding any prior records that are covered by the index without user intervention. If you ever experience indices missing data then you should contact us! As it happened today we had a brief outage that while it didn't prevent reads writes or index updates did stall index rebuilds.